# What is the name of the metal strip that goes over a step

Tags: steps

Between 2 rooms, there is a small single step, the step being only about 1-2 inches tall. Over this step is a piece of metal, bent in half. Mine has come undone, and has ended up broken but I've just found the same thing in another house. It looks like this:

[image]

Does this have a name? My own research gets me close with terms like "floor edge step trim" but most results I see have for flat pieces of metal, where I assume I'm after a "corner shaped" thing...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the term you want is 'stair nosing'. See here http://www.kofflersales.com/p/metal-stair-nosing.asp.